# Running node.js project on http request

Tags: node.js, automation, server

Consider having a team of developers working on some Node.js project and a single test-environment dev machine, for example, `dev.example.com`. Each developer works on project locally in their own feature branches (on git). From time to times developer wants to share his work with his or her teammates for code review demonstration or testing. Obvious way is to setup a personal project instance on shared machine, for example, `feature.user.dev.example.com`, and send link to all concerned.

I want to make this workflow more elegant. Since all developers commits to same remote repository, it's possible to automatically checkout and setup project instance from branch `feature` by `user` on first request to `feature.user.dev.example.com`.

Is there any ready solution for such idea?

What I am looking for is a some sort of deamon listening to requests and running specific commands like `mkdir /home/user/www/feature && git clone ... && make server`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of quite convenient ways to share your local progress with other developers through so called *local tunnel* services. For example `local-tunnel` [package](http://localtunnel.me/):

```
npm install -g localtunnel
$ lt --port 8000
your url is: https://gqgh.localtunnel.me
```

Now your local port is accessible from everywhere. I'm not quite sure that this is what you're looking for, though it worked for me and helped to save some time during the development.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I need. Tools like localtunnel or ngrok works if and only if developers has access to internet.